# Xamarin Forms custom control data binding issue

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a simple custom control that I am having trouble getting an exposed bindable Command property to work.

Here's the setup:  MainPage.xaml hosts CustomControl.xaml (*beige area below*).  CustomControl contains a Label and a Button.  MainPage contains the CustomControl, Entry, Label, and a Button.  All controls are bound to the CustomControlText property in the MainPageViewModel.  So as that property changes, all controls should update.

It mostly works...

Look at the demo video below.  I click the button on the MainPage, and all controls update including the custom control.  And when I change the Entry value, all fields update.  However, clicking 'Increment From CustomControl' does nothing.  It should invoke the SubmitCommand2 in the MainViewModel.

[image]

All my code is below (simple File/New Project example).  How would I change this code so clicking 'Increment From CustomControl' ultimately invokes the SubmitCommand2 Command in MainPageViewModel?

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App7"
             x:Class="App7.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <BoxView HeightRequest="100" />

        <local:CustomControl 
            Margin="50"
            WidthRequest="300"
            TextData="{Binding CustomControlText}" 
            Command="{Binding SubmitCommand2}"
        />

        <Entry Text="{Binding CustomControlText}" />

        <Label Text="{Binding CustomControlText}" />

        <Button Text="Increment from Main Page" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" />

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MainPageModel.cs**

```
public class MainPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    public MainPageModel() { }

    public string CustomControlText { get; set; }

    private int _index = 0;

    public Command SubmitCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                _index++;
                CustomControlText = $"Hello World {_index}";
            });
        }
    }

    public Command SubmitCommand2
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                _index++;
                _index++;
                CustomControlText = $"Hello World {_index}";
            });
        }
    }

    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        CustomControlText = "Hello World";

        base.Init(initData);
    }
}
```

**CustomControl.xaml**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App7.CustomControl"
             BackgroundColor="Beige"
             x:Name="this">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="entryControl"
                Placeholder="Enter Text"
                Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=TextData}"
            />
            <Button Text="Increment From CustomControl"
                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=Command}"
            />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**CustomControl.xaml.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CustomControl : ContentView
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        TextData = "";

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextDataProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                               propertyName: "TextData",
                                               returnType: typeof(string),
                                               declaringType: typeof(CustomControl),
                                               defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                               defaultValue: "");

    public string TextData
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(TextDataProperty).ToString(); }
        set { base.SetValue(TextDataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                               propertyName: "Command",
                                               returnType: typeof(Command),
                                               declaringType: typeof(CustomControl),
                                               defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public Command Command { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Command` property of `CustomControl` should also be implemented with `base.GetValue` and `base.SetValue`, same way as `TextData` is.

```
public partial class CustomControl : ContentView
{
    ...

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =   
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(Command),
            returnType: typeof(ICommand),
            declaringType: typeof(CustomControl),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
            defaultValue: default(ICommand));

    public ICommand Command 
    {
        get => (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: oops, yep, that was it!